# Android Studio não reconhece bibliotecas do Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Peguei um projeto que tem várias dependências externas, como lib do facebook, até mesmo algumas do próprio support android. O projeto compila normalmente e roda perfeitamente no device. O problema é que todas essas referências quando utilizadas no código não são encontradas pela IDE, exemplo no screenshot abaixo

[image: Código fica em vermelho como não encontrando as classes, porém compila e roda perfeitamente]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se ele roda normalmente mesmo estando assim, vá no seu Android Studio:

- Clique em "File"
- Depois em "Invalidate caches/ restart"
- E por fim confirme em "Invalidate and Restart"